# How do I add custom HTML into a menu?

Tags: menu-item, menu, custom-component

How do I add custom HTML into a menu? I wish to add this code as a menu item.

```
<form action="/your-server-side-code" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx LLC"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

It will show up as a button. I tried to select a Menu Item Type, but couldn't find anything that lets you enter HTML.

Joomla 3.8.2.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to find a menu extension (e.g. RokNavMenu) that lets you specify a Joomla module as the menu item.

You can then add the code to a Custom HTML module using Sourcerer or similar so that the code is not deleted when you save the module.

RokNavMenu: https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/roknavmenu

Regular Labs Sourcerer: https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/sourcerer

Comment: Possibly modules anywhere could do this too